# OrientDB: utf8 class name problems

Tags: java, utf-8, orientdb

I'am making an OGM to use in our project. It is working pretty well, but I have a problem with the class creation process and UTF8 character in the class name. 
We speak spanish, so some class have name using accent mark. The OGM try to create the classes using it's classname.
Here is a part of the store method:

```
public <T> String store(T o) throws IncorrectRIDField, NoOpenTx {
    String rid = null;
    try {
        // si no hay una tx abierta, disparar una excepción
        if (this.graphdb == null) {
            throw new NoOpenTx();
        }

        String classname = o.getClass().getSimpleName();

        ...
        ...
        ...

        // verificar que la clase existe
        if (this.getDBClass(o.getClass())==null){
            graphdb.createVertexType(classname);
        }


        OrientVertex v = graphdb.addVertex("class:" + classname, omap);
```

Well, the createVertexType work fine, but the addVertex("class:"... create another class with wrong name. Here is the output:

```
CLASSES
----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------+----------------+

 NAME                                         | SUPERCLASS                         | CLUSTERS   | RECORDS        |
----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
 _studio                                      |                                    | 11         |             23 |
 E                                            |                                    | 10         |              0 |
 OFunction                                    |                                    | 6          |              0 |
 OIdentity                                    |                                    | -          |              0 |
 ORestricted                                  |                                    | -          |              0 |
 ORIDs                                        |                                    | 8          |              0 |
 ORole                                        | [OIdentity]                        | 4          |              3 |
 OSchedule                                    |                                    | 7          |              0 |
 OTriggered                                   |                                    | -          |              0 |
 OUser                                        | [OIdentity]                        | 5          |              3 |
 Pa%C3%ADs                                    | [V]                                | 13         |              1 |
 Pa%C3%ADs_provincias                         | [E]                                | 16         |              0 |
 País                                         | [V]                                | 12         |              0 |
 Provincia                                    | [V]                                | 14         |              1 |
 Provincia_pa%C3%ADs                          | [E]                                | 15         |              1 |
 V                                            |                                    | 9          |              0 |
----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
 TOTAL = 16                                                                                                   32 |
----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
```

How could fix this? The edge, by default are created with the class name +  "_" + fieldname and have the same problems.

Any idea?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Could you open an issue on github ?

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a comment.